# Can we say $x^TABx \leq x^TBx$ if $(I-A)$ is positive semi-definite?

Tags: matrices, inequality, quadratic-forms, positive-semidefinite

I am reading a paper that tries to find an upper bound for a phrase and for this purpose, it uses something like the following:

$$ I - A \succeq 0 \quad \text{so} \quad A \preceq I \quad \text{then} \quad x^TABx \leq x^TBx $$

I can't find the proof of this term, maybe it is obvious, but I do not get the intuition or any proof for it. I would appreciate any hint for the proof.

Some information about $A$ and $B$ which might be helpful:

- $A$, $B$ and $AB$ are symmetric
- Both $A$ and $B$ are positive semi-definite

Comment: Obviously false without further information on $B$. What happens when you change $B$ to $-B$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your comment. Can we define any constraint on the $B$ to make it true? For example, if $B$ is also positive semi-definite, does that help?

Comment: We'd need $B$ to be positive semidefinte and to commute with $A$.

Comment: @Berci I think both exist. $B$ is positive semi-definite and both A and B are symmetric, so I think they commute. But what is the point in these two conditions? Would you please tell more?

Comment: $x^TBx-x^TABx=x^TB^{1/2}(I-A)B^{1/2}x\ge0$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo As I already told, I was reading the proof in a paper (there is a lot of information there) and it wasn't mentioned that being symmetric or other information is related to the proof. So I didn't know. My purpose is to find the answer, so I won't exclude information purposefully if I think they are necessary. We should give others the chance to sometimes be lost in a problem and don't know how to define it as a simple question. Thanks for your comment, I added them to the question.

Comment: @user137927 You are welcome.  Why not cite the paper? If the authors were sloppy, they deserve public criticism.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo To be honest, that is not my purpose in asking the question. My only goal was to understand the proof. But thanks a lot for the recommendation. I might one day also conclude that it is necessary to do so.

Comment: @user137927 If there's an error in the paper, then citing it may embarrass its authors a bit, which is bad, but it may also lead to a correction of the paper and the posting of a corrected version on arXiv, which is merciful towards readers.  I am on the readers' side.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your comment. In your proof, the condition is that $A$ and $B^{\frac{1}{2}}$ can commute, right? If $A$ and $B$ can commute, can we make sure that $A$ and $B^{\frac{1}{2}}$ will also do?

Comment: @user137927 Yes, because $B^{1/2}$ is a polynomial in $B$.

Comment: @user1551 yes, you are right, just wanted to make sure. Thanks a lot, I would appreciate it if you also add it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is positive semidefinite, there's an orthonormal basis $(e_i)$ of its eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\lambda_i\ge 0$, and we can verify the statement for $x=e_i$:
$${e_i}^TABe_i=\lambda_i\,{e_i}^TAe_i\le \lambda_i\,{e_i}^Te_i={e_i}^TABe_i\,.$$

Now if $A$ also commutes with $B$ ($AB=BA$) then they share a common orthonormal eigenbasis, and thus the above inequalities extend to any vector $x$ because all the mixed terms ${e_i}^TABe_j$ become zero with $i\ne j$.